# Unable to use snakemake after installation

Tags: snakemake

I installed snakemake with conta, i activated the environment and when I run **`snakemake --help`** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
> "/home/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/cli.py",
> line 2037, in main
>     parser, args = parse_args(argv)
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/cli.py",
> line 1629, in parse_args
>     parser = get_argument_parser()
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/cli.py",
> line 770, in get_argument_parser
>     lp_solvers = pulp.list_solvers(onlyAvailable=True)
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: module 'pulp' has no attribute 'list_solvers'. Did you mean: 'listSolvers'?
```

Can you help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure to install pulp<2.8.0

Comment: How can i install a pulp version < 2.8.0 ??

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge snakemake-minimal pulp "<2.8"

Comment: this is not working i have a message invalid package specification: <2.8. I am not able to find a way to downgrade this Pulp please help

Comment: I am using this : conda install -c conda-forge snakemake pulp"<=2.7 and I still have an error about PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: sorry, I usually install from yaml file. 
conda install bioconda::snakemake-minimal conda-forge::pulp=2.7.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @TobiasStraub please incorporate your comment responses into the answer. Users should not have to read comments to get a clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install snakemake with mamba, a fast and robust replacement of the conda package manager. It might resolve the issue of conflicting dependencies.

Use:

`mamba install -n snakemake snakemake`

This assumes that you installed mamba, i.e. via conda beforehand via `conda install mamba` into the base environment.